# PHP in_array() will not pass if...else

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

Here is my code:

```
$convertTitle = $this->art->catList(); // gets an array which has other arrays as its values
    foreach($convertTitle as $cT){ // cycle through the smaller arrays
        if(in_array($cat, $cT)){ // if "xx" is found in a smaller array
            $data['title'] = $cT['full']; // set the $title to the full form corresponding to the abbreviated xx ($cat) 
        }
        if(!in_array($cat, $cT)){ 
            $data['title'] = "Sorry, an error occurred."; // if it's not found, choose an alternate title 
            $data['error'] = 1; // throw the error
        } 
    }
```

In order to debug, I've been printing `in_array($cat, $cT)` and when I expect it to, it outputs 1. When I expect it to, it outputs 0 as well. So it seems like it's working.I can even `print($data['title']);` and the correct title shows up! But regardless of whether `in_array()` is outputting 1 or 0, my second if statement always overrides the first and I $error always comes out 1. What gives?

Some solutions I've tried:

```
if(!in_array($cat, $cT)... 
if(in_array($cat, $cT) == false/0/null)...
else...
```

I really have no idea why it's not outputting the proper title when the title *is* located in the variable when I want it to be!

EDIT: 
Here is `print_r($convertTitle);`

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [handle] => dr [full] => Drawings ) [1] => Array ( [handle] => f [full] => Films & Stills ) [2] => Array ( [handle] => pa [full] => Paintings ) [3] => Array ( [handle] => ph [full] => Photography ) [4] => Array ( [handle] => po [full] => Portraits ) )
```

Comment: You should probably just use an `else` statement instead of another `if` because your code paths *should* be mutually exclusive.  Also, can you include some examples of `$cat` and `$cT`?

Comment: Show me `print_r($convertTitle);`. Are you aware you can use `if(...){...}else{...}`?

Comment: I tried that and it still didn't work.

Comment: Once you set $data['error'] in the loop it will stay set. You're not handling that on subsequent loops.

Comment: what is stored in $cat? you are probably using in_array wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just an `else`?

```
if (in_array()) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

There's basically NO point in having two separate if() tests when the conditions are boolean opposites of each other.

Plus, recall that your `foreach()` will iterate MANY items. For **EVERY** item that isn't in your array, you set `$error` to be TRUE. But then you don't reset that to FALSE when you do make a match. so

```
array item #1 -> not found, so error => true
array item #2 -> not found, so error => true
array item #3 -> found! -> don't change error, it's still true
array item ....
etc...
```

Comment: @SanguineEpitaph Please think about Marc's last example. I think you have a logic problem instead of an `in_array`-problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your values in each iteration of the `foreach` loop, so you will end up with the result of the last value for the `title` and your `error` will remain set once it is set.

Apart from that, you should probably just write:

```
if (in_array()) {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers! I forgot that the loop would be running over and over even after it found the proper entry. For future reference, here is the code which works:

```
$convertTitle = $this->art->catList(); 
    foreach($convertTitle as $cT){ 
        if(in_array($cat, $cT)){ 
            $data['title'] = $cT['full']; 
            $data['error'] = 0; 
            break; 
        }
        else{ 
            $data['title'] = "Sorry, an error occurred."; 
            $data['error'] = 1; 
        } 
    }
```